# Changing value by id issue

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the value of data-value for the following piece of code:

```
<div class="media-body">
    <small>Total MA'ers found</small>
    <h2 id="totalma" class="media-heading animate-number" value="29" data-animation-duration="1500">0</h2>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
document.getElementById('totalma').data-value = 90;
```

Which returns the error: ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side

Comment: `document.getElementById('totalma').dataset.value = 90;` will set `data-value="90"`

Comment: is it `value`, or `data-value`?  Your HTML says the former, but the question says the latter.

Answer (score 6):

Try changing this:

```
document.getElementById('totalma').data-value = 90;
```

to this (if you want to change value attribute):

```
document.getElementById('totalma').setAttribute('value', 90);
```

to this (if you want to change/set data-value attribute):

```
document.getElementById('totalma').setAttribute('data-value', 90);
```

Answer (score 1):

`.data-value` isn't a legal JavaScript property name because of the hyphen, and in any event user specified DOM *attributes* aren't automatically mirrored into *properties*.

The correct method is therefore:

```
 document.getElementById('totalma').setAttribute('value', 90);
```

[An `<input>` element's `value` attribute and `.value` property *are* mirrored, but in this case you're using an `<h2>` element which has no such attribute / property].

If however, you actually meant to use the HTML5 attribute `data-value` then correct usage would be:

```
document.getElementById('totalma').dataset.value = 90;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setAttribute instead:

```
document.getElementById('totalma').setAttribute("value", 90);
```